# What does the "org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Checking" and for what?

Tags: geoserver

After launching the GeoServer, it prepares for map display for 60 seconds and processes data(layers, image pyramids).  Further, the processing of requests is fast.If no requests are received from the client to geoserver for a long time, the situation with long processing is repeated.

What does the "org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Checking" and for what?

```
2020-02-17 09:36:05,056 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/data/yamap/z18/O-36/O-36_2-5/0/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
2020-02-17 09:36:05,056 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/data/yamap/z18/O-36/O-36_2-5/0/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
2020-02-17 09:36:05,057 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/data/yamap/z18/O-36/O-36_2-5/0/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
2020-02-17 09:36:05,057 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/data/yamap/z18/O-36/O-36_2-5/0/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
2020-02-17 09:36:05,057 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/data/yamap/z18/O-36/O-36_2-5/0/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1580307269992
length:367708
2020-02-17 09:36:05,057 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/data/yamap/z18/O-36/O-36_2-5/0/
isHidden:false
exists:true
isFiletrue
canRead:true
canWritetrue
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:1580307269992
length:367708
2020-02-17 09:36:05,057 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Trying to load properties file from URL:file:/usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/data/yamap/z18/O-36/O-36_2-5/0/0.shp
2020-02-17 09:36:05,057 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Trying to load properties file from URL:file:/usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/data/yamap/z18/O-36/O-36_2-5/0/0.shp
2020-02-17 09:36:05,057 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/data/yamap/z18/O-36/O-36_2-5/0/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
2020-02-17 09:36:05,057 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/data/yamap/z18/O-36/O-36_2-5/0/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
2020-02-17 09:36:05,057 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/data/yamap/z18/O-36/O-36_2-5/0/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
2020-02-17 09:36:05,058 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Checking file:/usr/share/geoserver/bin/../data_dir/data/yamap/z18/O-36/O-36_2-5/0/
isHidden:false
exists:false
isFilefalse
canRead:false
canWritefalse
canExecute:false
isAbsolute:true
lastModified:0
length:0
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick check of the [code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/imagemosaic/src/main/java/org/geotools/gce/imagemosaic/Utils.java#L1056) shows this is looking for information on the file. The debug message you are seeing seems to come from [checkFileReadable()](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/imagemosaic/src/main/java/org/geotools/gce/imagemosaic/Utils.java#L1036), which is called from all over the place.

If you really want (need) to know then you can start [GeoServer up inside a debugger](https://gist.github.com/tbarsballe/f8a0109c22c3998e2af048d492f31cee) and add a breakpoint there to see where the calls come from.